# How to ignore gaps while drawing points using gl.POINTS in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, webgl2

```js
var gl, canvas;

const FLOAT_SIZE = 4;

var handleWebGLError = function (type, obj) {
 if (type === 'shader') {
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(obj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
   console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(obj));
   return null;
  }
 } else if (type === 'program') {
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(obj, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
   console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(obj));
   return null;
  }
 }
 
};

var getAndCompileShaders = function (id, type) {
 var shader = gl.createShader(type);
 var shaderText = document.getElementById(id).text.trim();
 gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderText);
 gl.compileShader(shader);
 handleWebGLError('shader', shader);
 return shader;
};

var getProgram = function (vsId, fsId, use) {
 var vs = getAndCompileShaders(vsId, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
 var fs = getAndCompileShaders(fsId, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 var program = gl.createProgram();
 gl.attachShader(program, vs);
 gl.attachShader(program, fs);
 gl.linkProgram(program);
 handleWebGLError('program', program);
 if (use) {
  gl.useProgram(program);
 }
 return program;
};

var createBuffer = function (gl, coords, isStatic) {
 var b = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, b);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(coords), isStatic ? gl.STATIC_DRAW : gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
 return b;
};

var createBuffers = function (gl, coordsArr, isStatic) {
 var bufferArr = [];
 coordsArr.forEach (function (coords) {
  var b = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, b);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(coords), isStatic ? gl.STATIC_DRAW : gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
  bufferArr.push(b);
 });
 return bufferArr;
};

var initWebGLCanvas = function (canvasId) {
 canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.90;
 canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.90;
 //get Context
 var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
 //assign a default color 
 gl.clearColor(0.002, 0.12, 0.3, 1.0);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 return gl;
};

var clearCanvas = function (gl) {
 gl.clearColor(0.002, 0.12, 0.3, 1.0);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

var fetchDataFromGPUAndRenderTrianglesToCanvas = function (o, gl) {
 o.buffer.forEach (function (data) {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(o.positionIndex, o.positionSize, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, o.stride*FLOAT_SIZE, o.positionOffset*FLOAT_SIZE);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(o.colorIndex, o.colorSize, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, o.stride*FLOAT_SIZE, o.colorOffset*FLOAT_SIZE); 
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, o.startIndexToDraw, o.numOfComponents);
 });
};

var fetchDataFromGPUAndRenderToCanvas = function (o, gl) {
 o.buffer.forEach (function (data) {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(o.positionIndex, o.positionSize, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE,
             (o.stride || 0)*FLOAT_SIZE, (o.colorOffset || 0)*FLOAT_SIZE);
        o.uniforms.forEach (function (uniform) {
            gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, uniform.key), uniform.value);
        });
  gl.drawArrays(o.drawingType, o.startIndexToDraw, o.numOfComponents);
 });
};

var enableVerticesToPickBinaryDataWithinGPU = (position, color) => {
    if (position) {
        gl.positionIndex = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, position);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.positionIndex);
    }

    if (color) {
        gl.colorIndex = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, color);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.colorIndex);
    }
};

var getSampleTriangleUsingPoints = () => {
    //left
    var triangleVertices = new Float32Array(20 + 2 + 20 + 20);
    for (var i = 0; i < 19; i = i + 2) {
        var lastX = i === 0 ? -1.1 : triangleVertices[i - 2];
        var lastY = i === 0 ? -1.2 : triangleVertices[i - 1];
        triangleVertices[i] = lastX + 0.1;
        triangleVertices[i + 1] = lastY + 0.2;
    }
 //top
 triangleVertices[20] = 0.0; triangleVertices[21] = 1.0; 

 //right
    for (var i = 22; i < 40; i = i + 2) {
        triangleVertices[i] = triangleVertices[i - 2] + 0.1;
        triangleVertices[i + 1] = triangleVertices[i - 1] - 0.2;
 }
 
 triangleVertices[40] = 1.0; triangleVertices[41] = -1.0; 
 
 //bottom
 var x = -1.0, y = -1.0;
 for (var i = 42; i <= 60; i = i + 2) {
  if (i !== 42) {
   x += 0.2;
  }
  triangleVertices[i] = x;
        triangleVertices[i + 1] = y;
 }
    
 //allocate a memory in GPU
 var verticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 //link CPU variable to point to GPU using gl.ARRAY_BUFFER gate
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer);
 //Send data to the memory location allocated above, gl.STATIC_DRAW means vertices won't be changed later and GPU will store the vertices far from the CPU.
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    return verticesBuffer;
}

var getBufferUsingPoints = function (points) {
    var f32a = new Float32Array(points);
    //allocate a memory in GPU
 var verticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 //link CPU variable to point to GPU using gl.ARRAY_BUFFER gate
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer);
 //Send data to the memory location allocated above, gl.STATIC_DRAW means vertices won't be changed later and GPU will store the vertices far from the CPU.
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, f32a, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    return verticesBuffer;
};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 //resize canvas
 gl = initWebGLCanvas('canvas');
 gl.program = getProgram('vertexShader', 'fragmentShader', true);
 
 clearCanvas(gl);
 var isDragging = false;
 var points = [];
 var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
 clear.onclick = () => {
  points = [];
  clearCanvas(gl);
 };

 canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
  isDragging = false;
 };

 canvas.onmouseout = (e) => {
  isDragging = false;
 };

 canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
 };

 canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (isDragging) {
   clearCanvas(gl);
   enableVerticesToPickBinaryDataWithinGPU('position');
   points.push(-1.0 + e.offsetX/canvas.width*2.0, 1.0 - e.offsetY/canvas.height*2.0);
   var pointsBuffer = getBufferUsingPoints(points);
   fetchDataFromGPUAndRenderToCanvas({
    positionIndex : gl.positionIndex,
    buffer : [pointsBuffer],
    positionSize : 2,
    uniforms : [{key : 'vSize', value : 1/canvas.width}],
    startIndexToDraw : 0,
    numOfComponents : points.length/2,
    drawingType : gl.POINTS
   }, gl);
  }
 };
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  
  <script type="vertexShader" id="vertexShader">
 #version 300 es
 in vec2 position;
 in vec4 color;
 out vec4 fcolor;
 uniform float vSize;
 void main () {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  fcolor = color;
 }
</script>

<script type="fragmentShader" id="fragmentShader">
 #version 300 es
 precision mediump float;
 in vec4 fcolor;
 out vec4 finalColor;
 void main () {
  finalColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 }
</script>
```

I was trying to implement a solution in WebGL where I was able to draw points dynamically by dragging mouse. But if I drag too fast, I can see a gap between the points and if I increase the size of points using `gl_PointSize` it does increase the size of the points and saves the gap but I don't think that's correct.

Can we try something else to render the points altogether.

Comment: How about just drawing a line instead of points?

Comment: I am looking to draw freely not a straight line. I think gl.POINTS is the only option but it shows gaps when dragged too fast

Comment: That's why you'd use `gl.LINE` to draw small line segments between your vertices instead of points.

Comment: ok sounds like it will solve my problem , let me try that out

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug using only code you posted in the question itself therefore this question is off topic for stack overflow. Please put the code **in the question itself**. I suggest you use a use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: ok @gman I added the snippet, btw nice suggestion I will not have to use fiddle from now for asking question on SO. Can you check now?

Comment: You can include external scripts in your snippet, just as `<script src=“path/to/library”></script>` just as long as they aren’t relevant to the issue (and better if they are served from a versioned CDN so they won’t change and ruin the question)